# error while trying print to several files in bash scripts

Tags: bash, writetofile

I've got a problem related to write to files.
I've created `server/client` in `c` (for `Linux`, via `sockets`).
I want the `clients` to save a log file with all the actions they did. When I open a client and transfer file everything is OK but when I check my server's multi requests support (by creating a bash script that checks it all) I discovered that none of my clients write anything.

Client command is: `./client_prog host port file_to_receive log_file`

Script:

```
cd client1/
./client_prog localhost 22222 file.txt log &
cd client2/
./client_prog localhost 22222 file.txt log &
cd client3/
./client_prog localhost 22222 file.txt log &
#more clients....
```

each client create log thread and with pipe transferring data, and the log thread write it with `fopen`(), `fprintf`() and `fclose`().

BTW, when I try from two different terminals, it's working fine.
It doesn't make any sense..

Thanks!

Comment: do you have a copy of `client_prog` in each of the `clientN/` subdirectories? And shouldn't it be `cd ../client2` (from `client1`) if all your `clientN/` directories have the common parent

Comment: are you passing the full path of the log file when calling your command?

Answer (score 0):

Is that your exact script (or a simplified spinet)?

Are you sure you don't want to do a '**cd ..**' prior to trying to move to the other client directories (after the first client)?  Cause if your initial '**cd client2**' fails, then you'll end up trying to start a client using the same '**file.txt**' and '**log**' which could cause you some errors?